# Unix Sql -- Updating One table from a 2nd table -- null value issue

Tags: sql, oracle

I have been looking at the web for hours trying to determine what is wrong with my code.  I keep receiving the ORA-01407: cannot update ("AMIOWN"."MEMBER"."LANGUAGE_X") to NULL.   I need to update the language in the member table when the language in the contract table is not null.  The 3rd table is required in order to drill down to specific members. Below is the code:

```
update member m
    set language_x =
    (select language_x
        from contract c
        where m.contract_nbr  = c.contract_nbr and
        c.language_x is not null and
        m.member_nbr =
        (select member_nbr
            from member_span ms
            where m.member_nbr = ms.member_nbr and
            ms.void     = ' ' and
            ms.carrier  = 'PM' and
            ms.prog_nbr = 'GP' and
            ms.region   = 'TR' and
            (ms.ymdeff <= 20160218 or ms.ymdeff > 20160218) and
            ms.ymdend > 20160218
        )
    );
```

Some of the postings also suggested adding another line after the last parenthesis checking for:

where exists (select 1 from contract c where m.contract_nbr = c.contract_nbr and c.language_x is not null);

I am working in a unix environment, tables are contained in an amisys database.

Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: There's almost certainly a better way to write the query than with all of those subselects. Without seeing your data structure or sample data, etc. it's impossible to even try though. Also, without seeing any data it's impossible to know what the issue is except to say that there probably isn't a row that matches your criteria. Using `c.language_x is not null` within the subselect isn't going to help avoid the issue if it's not finding a match at all.

Comment: There are records that meet the criteria.  All data was analyzed before writing the code.

Comment: I guess that everyone will have to take your word for it,

Answer (score 0):

you need to add the where condition to your update statement

```
update member m
    set language_x = (select language_x
                        from contract c
                       where m.contract_nbr  = c.contract_nbr 
                         and c.language_x is not null 
                         and m.member_nbr = (select member_nbr
                                              from member_span ms
                                             where m.member_nbr = ms.member_nbr 
                                               and ms.void     = ' ' 
                                               and ms.carrier  = 'PM' 
                                               and ms.prog_nbr = 'GP' 
                                               and ms.region   = 'TR' 
                                               and (ms.ymdeff <= 20160218 or ms.ymdeff > 20160218) 
                                               and ms.ymdend > 20160218)
    )
    where exists (select language_x
                        from contract c
                       where m.contract_nbr  = c.contract_nbr 
                         and c.language_x is not null 
                         and m.member_nbr = (select member_nbr
                                              from member_span ms
                                             where m.member_nbr = ms.member_nbr 
                                               and ms.void     = ' ' 
                                               and ms.carrier  = 'PM' 
                                               and ms.prog_nbr = 'GP' 
                                               and ms.region   = 'TR' 
                                               and (ms.ymdeff <= 20160218 or ms.ymdeff > 20160218) 
                                               and ms.ymdend > 20160218)
    );
```

Below is a more elegant solution, but depending on your datamodel it might or might not work

```
Update    
(
select m.language_x as oldval 
       c.language_x as newval
  from member m
      ,contract c
where m.contract_nbr  = c.contract_nbr 
  and c.language_x is not null 
  and m.member_nbr = (select member_nbr
                        from member_span ms
                       where m.member_nbr = ms.member_nbr 
                         and ms.void     = ' ' 
                         and ms.carrier  = 'PM' 
                         and ms.prog_nbr = 'GP' 
                         and ms.region   = 'TR' 
                         and (ms.ymdeff <= 20160218 or ms.ymdeff > 20160218) 
                         and ms.ymdend > 20160218)
) t
set t.oldval =t.newval
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I tried both approaches.  You were correct on the 2nd query as it would not run in our environment, ORA-01779.  The first option is running, although somewhat slow, but that could have something to do with our DEV environment as it is much, much slower than PROD.  I'm going to continue to work with the code to see if I can fine tune it.